# os.sytem() in Python gives infinite loop

Tags: python, process, operating-system, subprocess, multiprocessing

My main Python script imports 2 other scripts; Test1.py and Test2.py.

Test1.py does multiprocessing, and Test2.py does a simple os.system('ls') command. When Test1.py is finished and Test.py is called, os.system(ls) is going crazy and creates infinite new processes. Does anyone know why this happens?

```
# Main
import multiprocessing
import Test1.py
import Test2.py

def doSomething():
    # Function 1, file1...file10 contain [name, path]
    data = [file1, file2, file3, file4, file5, file6, file7, file8, file9, file10]
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=min(len(data), 5))
        print pool.map(Test1.worker, data)

    # Function 2
    Test2.worker()
```

Test1.py; calls perl commands

```
def worker(data):
    command = 'perl '+data[1].split('data_')[0]+'methods_FastQC\\fastqc '+data[1]+'\\'+data[0]+'\\'+data[0]+' --outdir='+data[1]+'\\_IlluminaResults\\_fastqcAnalysis'
    process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    process.wait()
    process.stdout.read()
```

Test2.py should do ONE simple ls command, instead it never stops making new commands;

```
def worker():
    command = 'ls'
    os.system(command)
```

When looking at the processes if script is started, it seems like the processes after function1 also don't close properly. Via the Taskmanager I still see 5 extra pythonw.exe which don't seem to do anything. Only when I close the opened shell they go away. Thats probably related to why os.system(command) goes crazy in function 2? Does anyone have a solution, since I can't close the shell because the script is not finished since it still has to do function2?

Edit: When trying to find a solution, it also happened that function1 started with executing the commands from function(2) multiple times, and after that the perl commands. Which is even more weird.

Comment: There is something strange in the listings above. How do you type `import Test2.py` and  not get an error? The import statement uses the module name, without the ".py" part, not the full filename.

Comment: Are you on Windows? Mulitprocessing's [programming guidelines](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#windows) says, "Make sure that the main module can be safely imported by a new Python interpreter without causing unintended side effects (such a starting a new process)." Could this be the cause of your problem? Your main is starting new processes via `map`, isn't it?

Comment: unrelated: don't use `stdout=PIPE` unless you read from it while the process is running otherwise `process.wait()` will wait forever. Try `subprocess.check_output()` and `os.path.join()` to make your code work

Comment: I hope that you are using "ls" as a test only - and you are not seriously using this method to get directory listings. There are far better ways to do that.

Answer (score 0):

It seems `doSomething()` is executed every time your main module is imported and it can be imported several times by `multiprocessing` during the workers initialization. You could check it by printing process pid: `print(os.getpid())` in `Test2.worker()`.

You should use `if __name__ == '__main__':` *at the module level*. It is error-prone to do it inside a function as your code shows.

```
import multiprocessing

# ...

if __name__ == '__main__': # at global level
    multiprocessing.freeze_support()
    main() # it calls do_something() and everything else
```

See the very first note in [the introduction to `multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/multiprocessing.html).